# Acomodar automaticamente los elementos de mi form dependiendo del tamaño del mismo en C#

Tags: c#

Tengo un Formulario en C#, si maximizo el form todo se queda del mismo tamaño y en el mismo lugar.[image: Este es mi formulario]

Quisiera saber como ajustar los objetos depediendo del tamaño del formulario.
Gracias.

Comment: Es Winforms? WPF? UWP?

Answer (score 2):

Si es para Winforms, puedes usar un [TableLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/3a1tbfwd(v=vs.110).aspx)

Arrastralo desde la barra de herramientas al formulario
Establece la propiedad "Dock" en full
Establece la cantidad de filas y columnas
Arrastra controles a sus casillas

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que usar la propiedad anchor de los objetos y ajustarla a form para que se agranden y se achiquen a la par de ellos.

Ten cuidado porque si solo "anclas" un lado del objeto, se extendera para ese lado, pero tambien se movera. Tenes que fijarte que es lo que queres y jugar con eso.

Igual solo los objetos imagenes se suelen anclar, y se ponen dentro de contenedores por lo general... Uno no agranda botones o campos de texto, salvo que seas un editor de texto.

Answer (score 0):

Si es con WPF puedes hacerlo poniendo * o auto a tus controles, así cuando el formulario cambie de tamaño, este cambiara con el mismo.

Si es en WinForms puedes usar el  AutoScaleMode.

[aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms229605(v=vs.110).aspx) te explica como se usan estos

Comment: Hola Ezequiel, si la pregunta no esta clara es preferible comentar y pedir aclaraciones antes de responder. Quiza te interese leer esto: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/587/25 Salu2